# Execute dataflow job from App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am relatively new in GCP technology. Currently, I am a doing POC to create a scheduled dataflow job that ingest (insert) data from google cloud storage to BigQuery. After reading some tutorials and documentations, I come up with the following:

1. I first create a dataflow job that read an avro file and load it to BigQuery. This dataflow has been tested and worked well.

   ```
   (self.pipeline
        | output_table + ': read table ' >> ReadFromAvro(storage_input_path)
        | output_table + ': filter columns' >> beam.Map(self.__filter_columns, columns=columns)
        | output_table + ': write to BigQuery' >> beam.Write(
           beam.io.BigQuerySink(output_table,               
      create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER,                               
      write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)))
   ```
2. In order to create the scheduled job, I then created a simple web service as follows:

   ````
   import logging
   from flask import Flask
   from common.tableLoader import TableLoader
   from ingestion import IngestionToBigQuery
   from common.configReader import ConfigReader
   app = Flask(__name__)
   @app.route('/')
   def hello():
        """Return a friendly HTTP greeting."""
       logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
       config = ConfigReader('columbus-config')  # TODO read from args
       tables = TableLoader('experience')
       ingestor = IngestionToBigQuery(config.configuration, tables.list_of_tables)
       ingestor.ingest_table()
       return 'Hello World!'```
   ````
3. I also created the app.yaml:

   ```
    runtime: python
    env: flex
    entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT recsys_data_pipeline.main:app
    threadsafe: yes
    runtime_config:
       python_version: 2
       resources:
       memory_gb: 2.0
   ```

Then, I deployed it using this command `gcloud app deploy`, yet, I got the following errors:

```
default[20170417t173837]  ERROR:root:The gcloud tool was not found.
default[20170417t173837]  Traceback (most recent call last):    
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/gcp/auth.py", line 109, in _refresh      ['gcloud', 'auth', 'print-access-token'], stdout=processes.PIPE)    
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/processes.py", line 52, in Popen      return subprocess.Popen(*args, **kwargs)    
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__      errread, errwrite)    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child      raise child_exception  OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

From the message above, I found that error was coming from the `apache_beam auth.py class`, specifically, it was coming from the following function:

```
def _refresh(self, http_request):
   """Gets an access token using the gcloud client."""
   try:
     gcloud_process = processes.Popen(['gcloud', 'auth', 'print-access-token'], stdout=processes.PIPE)
   except OSError as exn:
     logging.error('The gcloud tool was not found.', exc_info=True)
     raise AuthenticationException('The gcloud tool was not found: %s' % exn)
  output, _ = gcloud_process.communicate()
  self.access_token = output.strip()
```

which was invoked when the credentials (`service_acount_name` and `service_acount_key` are not given:

```
if google_cloud_options.service_account_name:
      if not google_cloud_options.service_account_key_file:
        raise AuthenticationException(
            'key file not provided for service account.')
      if not os.path.exists(google_cloud_options.service_account_key_file):
        raise AuthenticationException(
            'Specified service account key file does not exist.')

else:
      try:
        credentials = _GCloudWrapperCredentials(user_agent)
        # Check if we are able to get an access token. If not fallback to
        # application default credentials.
        credentials.get_access_token()
        return credentials
```

So I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to "attach" the credentials (the `service_acount_name` and `service_acount_key`) somewhere in my  code or in the config file (for instance: in `app.yaml`)?
2. What are the best practices to trigger a dataflow job from google app engine?

Thank you so much, any suggestions and comments would be really helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at an official example of this at https://github.com/amygdala/gae-dataflow .

Comment: hei @jkff thanks for your reply. I tried the step by step provided in the link above, yet, I still get the same error when deploying the app.yaml. `ERROR:root:The gcloud tool was not found.`

Comment: Are you using `custom` runtime in your app.yaml and do you have the `Dockerfile` from Amy's example beside it in the directory?

Comment: I do use `custom` runtime in my app.yaml. I also created the `Dockerfile`, same as the Amy's example.

Comment: @bohr - in your example above, you're using `runtime: python`.  To double check, did you change that to `runtime: custom` as done [here](https://github.com/amygdala/gae-dataflow/blob/master/backend.yaml#L16)? You should see the dockerfile build output (including the gcloud install) as part of the deploy process.

Comment: hi @AmyU.I've finally managed to submit the job. Thanks to the link provided. I decided to create a new project and start adopting you example. Thanks